# Why I can't access to the CSS resources defined into the \webapp\resources\ folder of this Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources, freemarker

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem into a Spring MVC project that use FreeMarker for my views.

I am finding some problems trying to import some resources (CSS files and images defined into the `myProject\src\main\webapp\resources\` directory of my project).

So I have this `header.ftl` file that represent the header of all my pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js is-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>MY WEBSITE</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/webfont.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bs-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bs-dialog/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />

</head>

<body id="main">
    <div class="container page-header">
        <h1>My WebSite</h1>
    </div>
```

So, as you can see, I am importing some css resources that are defined into `myProject\src\main\webapp\resources\` directory into my project.

The problem is that these resources are not imported in my project (so I have no CSS settings).

This is the rendered output for the previous CSS resources looking the generated HTML code in FirFox:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/webfont.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bs-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bs-dialog/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />
```

The only Spring xml configuration file in this project is named **web-context.xml** (it is where **FreeMarker** is configured and where is speciied the component scan for my controller), this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Attivazione dei Proxy tramite aspetto -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true" />

    <!-- Controller -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="it.istruzione.iam.ssum.registrazione">
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Configurazione del resolver FreeMarker -->
    <!-- freemarker config -->
    <bean id="freemarkerConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configurazione MVC -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

As you can see I have add this line to try to handle the request toward the content of the `/resources/` directory:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

But it still doesn't work and I can't access to my CSS resources placed ins `/resources/` subdirectories.

When I show the previous page into the browser, into the Eclipse console I obtain the following error messages related to these resources:

```
16:55:40,249 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started (with errors) in 13261ms - Started 176 of 240 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 59 services are passive or on-demand)
16:55:42,623 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,624 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/css/webfont.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,640 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/css/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,658 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/assets/js/modernizr-custom.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,659 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,661 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/plugins/bs-select/bootstrap-select.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,664 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-5) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/plugins/bs-dialog/bootstrap-dialog.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
16:57:14,664 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSTL` `to make sure that your urls are correct:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/webfont.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Edit** sorry  i didn't notice it's a freemarker page:

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />

<link href="<@spring.url '/resources/css/webfont.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Can I really use JSTL inside a FreeMarker page? Is it not something related to JSP page? It is seems me wired

Comment: Ok, but I think that it is clearer configure the resources mapping into the Spring XML configuration, but it can't work

Comment: @AndreaNobili if you directly call `http://localhost:xxxx/yourProject/resources/css/webfont.css` what do you get ?

Comment: Rafik BELDI: Opening this URL: http://localhost:8080/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/resources/css/webfont.css I obtain the CSS file content !!! The problem is that, as you an see at the end of my original post, it try to find it using the URL: /iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/css/webfont.css (after the project name it try to find the resources folder into the iscrizione folder that is the name of the opened page)

Comment: Infact it give me this error message: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/iam-ssum-registrazione-web/iscrizione/resources/css/webfont.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: @AndreaNobili yes I know that's why we want to add the <@spring.url> tag so it will get the absolute path not the relative one (to the specific page)